# How can I recreate this shiny chrome effect?

Tags: effects

[image]

I need to know how this shiny almost wet effect with the text. It also appears to have a ring light of some sort seen in the letter. I've tried principled BSDF node with metallic all the way up but it just doesn't look right. I've also tried using an environment texture (studio 2 from polyhaven). The second time I tried to use it without the hdr. This is what mine currently looks like
[image]

Comment: With a metallic surface, all reflections get the tint of the base color - that's a characteristic of metallic surfaces. This way you cannot get the white reflections on the object. What you can do to have metallic and "normal" reflections is setting _Metallic_ to 1 with a bit of roughness like 0.3 or so (as you like) and also set the _Clearcoat_ to 1 with that low default _Clearcoat Roughness_. This way the metal surface gets a shiny reflective layer on top of it. Also, to have awesome reflections you need something in the environment that can be reflected.

Comment: are you need source files? hahaha carefully [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLBM7.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLBM7.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

For me it's more plastic that metallic, you could lower down the *Roughness* and increase the *Specular*, also mix the *Principled BSDF* with another one with a darker color, with a *Layer Weight* as factor in order to create a darker outline around the letter:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, what did you do for the lighting?

Comment: A studio hdri and 3 area lights